# Stopping task while blocking

Tags: multitasking, ada

Let me illustrate this question with code first:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test
is

   task type Serving_Task is
      entry Start;
   end Serving_Task;

   task body Serving_Task is begin
      accept Start;
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Started");
      loop
         null; --  Blocking operation, eg. accepting on a socket.
         null; --  Processing on blocking operation's result.
      end loop;
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Stopped");
   end Serving_Task;

   type Server is tagged limited record
      Serving : Serving_Task;
   end record;

   procedure Start
     (S : in out Server)
   is begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Starting");
      S.Serving.Start;
   end Start;

   procedure Stop
     (S : in out Server)
   is begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Stopping");
      -- TODO To implement.
   end Stop;

   Main_Server : Server;

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Calling Start");
   Start (Main_Server);
   delay 5.0;
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Calling Stop");
   Stop (Main_Server);
end Test;
```

This is typical server construct - there's a server task with a loop accepting incoming connections. My question is - what is the best way to implement `Stop` procedure for `Server` type.

I'd like it to wait until the serving task blocks on accepting a socket (or just before the blocking call, so every accepted request if fully handled before terminating the task) and exit the loop, so the task can clean up before terminating.

First thing that comes to mind is adding

```
select
   accept Stop;
or
   delay 0.1;
   exit;
end select;
```

at the end of the loop, but that's 0.1 second wasted on each iteration. Seems significant.

I've looked at some examples in RM, Lovelace tutorial and Wikibook, but nothing really seemed appropriate.

What is the best practice for such (fairly common I believe) problem in Ada?

**And the answer is...**

Example solution based on [Marc C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38706/marc-c)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037736/1333261): https://gist.github.com/3413017

Comment: Do you want your server to only run for 5 seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I typically set this up is first by using AdaCore's GNAT.Sockets package, rather than directly programming the sockets. Since I'll be using the (socket) select() function (which is wrapped as Check_Selector) to be notified when data is available on the socket, GNAT.Sockets provides an Abort_Selector() procedure that can be invoked from elsewhere. With the task blocked on Check_Selector(), I just wait for data to arrive (Status = Completed) or the flag that it's time to exit (Status = Aborted).

See the start of the Monitor_Connections procedure (lines 397-416ish) in the TOMI_4_Ada package [TCP_Connect](http://tomi4ada.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tomi4ada/trunk/src/tomi_4_ada-transport-tcp_connect.adb?revision=64&view=markup). Monitor_Connections is invoked from task Connection_Monitoring (lines 469-495).

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! Can I be sure of GNAT.Sockets selectors thread safety?

Comment: @MikołajSiedlarek: I strongly doubt it. I dedicate a selector, and the socket(s) it monitors, to a task--no sharing. (There are ways to share sockets amongst tasks, but I almost always prefer to dedicate them.)

Comment: That's probably good enough for me, as I just want to terminate the server on certain interrupt.

Comment: For future generations I leave here link to example solution based on your answer: https://gist.github.com/3413017 . Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You want the [else](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-7-1.html#p19) version:

```
loop
   -- blocking read from socket
   -- process the data received
   select
      accept Stop;
      exit;
   else
      null;
   end select;
end loop;
```

Comment: The problem with this, though, is that you're now spinning in a busy loop.

Comment: Mikolaj said "I'd like it to wait until the serving task blocks on accepting a socket (or just before the blocking call, so every accepted request if fully handled before terminating the task) and exit the loop, so the task can clean up before terminating". "do stuff" is meant to involve blocking on a socket and processing the eventual input. Will amend the answer. I agree that breaking out of the blocking socket call, while desirable, is more difficult.